# SOAP service and HTTP Post with same business logic on Mule ESB

Tags: mule, esb

I have to provide a SOAP web service on Mule.

```
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

import bean.SubscriberBean;

@WebService
public interface SubscribeService {

    @WebMethod(operationName = "subscribe")
    public void subscribe(String email, Boolean digest);
}
```

I'm using `<cxf:jaxws-service/>` for that. But I also need to provide the same service with a HTTP Post from a static HTML page. Whats the best way to design this?

Answer (score 0):

- Configure `SubscribeService` as a Spring bean,
- Use it in your flow with `cxf:jaxws-service`,
- Create another flow with a different path for the non-SOAP interface,
- In this new flow, call the `SubscribeService` Spring bean with the `invoke` message processor.

Comment: Is the SubscribeService that should be configured? Or the actual implementation? Sorry I'm new to Mule and cant grasp how some things work.

Comment: Im lost, i cant find any documentation on this. Can you please give me a demo on a simple subscribe implementation?

Comment: You're asking for an implementation of the above interface? That's not Mule related in any way, moreover this completely depends on what you want to do. Just create a class that implements `SubscribeService` and that satisfies your needs. Then configure it like any standard Spring bean and then use it in a Mule `<component/><spring-bean ref="yourBeanName"/></component>`